# Android Gradle: Dynamically change versionName at build time

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to emulate Maven release plugin in Android by using a customized version of gradle-release plugin: https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release

The interesting steps are:

- Check uncommitted changes
- Step version code and remove -SNAPSHOT
  suffix from version name
- Build
- Step version name and add -SNAPSHOT
  suffix for next development version

However the generated APK always has the previous versions (i.e. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0.0).

Version numbers are stored and correctly updated in gradle.properties, so I'm assuming that I need to update the versions in the data model as well for the changes to take effect.

My android plugin config:

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode versionCode as int  // taken from gradle.properties
    versionName versionName // taken from gradle.properties
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Things I tried:

```
preBuild << {
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        variant.versionName = versionName
    }
}
```

But there's no versionName in a variant.

```
preBuild << {
    android.buildTypes.each { type ->
        type.versionName = versionName
    }
}
```

But there's no versionName in a type.

```
preBuild << {
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        flavor.versionName = versionName
    }
}
```

But there are no flavors in my app (plain debug and release build types only).

My alternative is to write a bash/bat script to step the versions before invoking Gradle, which pretty much defeats the purpose of using Groovy to improve build customization.

How can I update versions dynamically in the Android Gradle plugin in the execution phase?

Comment: I found your question after posting mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818755/android-build-with-gradle-release-plugin, did you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry but no, I ended up coding the bash/bat script that changes the version, now I have Windows and Unix specific code to maintain :(

Comment: Haha, I created custom scripts too, but I wrote them as Gradle tasks, so they are crossplatform :)

Comment: `variant.mergedFlavor` is what you need

Answer (score 59):

That's what `buildTypes` are for. What you're describing is a `release` build, IMO.

Here's an example: when executing `assembleDebug` it will give you a snapshot build, and executing `assembleRelease` will give you a clean build without any suffix and incremented version number. The next debug build will also use the incremented number.

The following is a fully functional build when the files are created in a folder. It should also work with flavors, but that's just a side product :). Gradle 2.2.1, Android plugin 1.1.3

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'auto-version.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3' }
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"
    compileSdkVersion = "android-21"

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-SNAPSHOT"
        }
    }
}

println "config code: ${calculateVersionCode()}, name: ${calculateVersionName()}"
```

## src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest package="com.example" />
```

## auto-version.gradle

```
ext {
    versionFile = new File(project.rootDir, 'version.properties')
    calculateVersionName = {
        def version = readVersion()
        return "${version['major']}.${version['minor']}.${version['build']}"
    }
    calculateVersionCode = {
        def version = readVersion()
        def major = version['major'] as int // 1..∞
        def minor = version['minor'] as int // 0..99
        def build = version['build'] as int // 0..999
        return (major * 100 + minor) * 1000 + build
    }
}


Properties readVersion() {
    def version = new Properties()
    def stream
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(versionFile)
        version.load(stream)
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ignore) {
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) stream.close()
    }
    // safety defaults in case file is missing
    if(!version['major']) version['major'] = "1"
    if(!version['minor']) version['minor'] = "0"
    if(!version['build']) version['build'] = "0"
    return version
}

void incrementVersionNumber() {
    def version = readVersion()

    // careful with the types, culprits: "9"++ = ":", "9" + 1 = "91"
    def build = version['build'] as int
    build++
    version['build'] = build.toString()

    def stream = new FileOutputStream(versionFile)
    try {
        version.store(stream, null)
    } finally {
        stream.close()
    }
}

task incrementVersion {
    description "Increments build counter in ${versionFile}"
    doFirst {
        incrementVersionNumber()
    }
}

if (plugins.hasPlugin('android') || plugins.hasPlugin('android-library')) {
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            versionName = calculateVersionName()
            versionCode = calculateVersionCode()
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            def autoIncrementVariant = { variant ->
                if (variant.buildType.name == buildTypes.release.name) { // don't increment on debug builds
                    variant.preBuild.dependsOn incrementVersion
                    incrementVersion.doLast {
                        variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = calculateVersionName()
                        variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = calculateVersionCode()
                    }
                }
            }
            if (plugins.hasPlugin('android')) {
                applicationVariants.all { variant -> autoIncrementVariant(variant) }
            }
            if (plugins.hasPlugin('android-library')) {
                libraryVariants.all { variant -> autoIncrementVariant(variant) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execute `gradle assembleDebug` to build normally, `gradle assembleRelease` to increment and build, and `gradle incrementVersion` to just increment.
*Note: be careful with `gradle assemble` because the order of `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease` will yield different results.*

Check the generated files in the `build` directory to see if the values are to your liking.

## Manual execution (from comments)

It is possible you have multiple flavors in which case the version is incremented multiple times because multiple variants match the release build type. The original quesion was for no flavors. If you want to have more control when the version number is incremented just remove the `afterEvaluate` block and call the `incrementVersion` task whenever you want:

```
gradle incrementVersion assembleFreeRelease assemblePaidRelease
```

(The above manual execution is an untested idea.)

## Check uncommitted changes

The "Check uncommitted changes" are not covered in this answer, that's another game. You could hook on to `tasks.preBuild.doFirst { /*fail here if uncommited changes*/ }` if I understand correctly. But that highly depends on your version control. Ask another question for more!

Comment: While I'm not sure if this is the best answer for the specifics of the question, it answers the title, and the question which brought me here from google, so I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: This works only partly. The version is read from the file, but never incremented! I logged and saw that ``incrementVersionNumber()`` is never called. It seems that the check ``if (variant.buildType == buildTypes.release)`` is never true, for whatever reason. Replacing it with ``if (variant.name == "release")`` worked for me.

Comment: @Dadou thanks for alerting, I updated the answer to latest versions and fixed it. They introduced read-only buildTypes around 0.14.x and it seems that the two read-only wrappers are created separately.

Comment: And for me it always increments twice (even on debug builds) ;/

Comment: @meeDamian You probably have two flavors defined (free, paid?) in which case there will be 4 variants and 2 of those are "release". Without more info I don't have any idea for your "debug builds". You can create a new question and link it here it's easier to answer if there's more space for a full question. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Nope, it always goes through "release" and "debug" variants, I think it might be Android Studio dry-running stuff (or sth similar) - trying to pinpoint it now.

Comment: @WOLVERINE You can see the format from the `readVersion` method source.  Running `gradle incrementVersion` will also create the File for you.

Comment: @meeDamian This code is always incrementing the versionCode because it's always iterating through every build variant.  To stop it I used this function `boolean isRelease() {
    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    return ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks)
}`  in conjunction with `variant.buildType.name == buildTypes.release.name`

Comment: @BronDavies notice that it augments all variants, but only adds to their tasks' `doLast`, and that added closure is only executed if `x in runTasks`. It may need a revision, because it was written for a much older Android plugin. I think your best bet would be to what is in the manual execution. Just run `gradle incrementVersion` whenever you want separately.

Answer (score 19):

I needed to append current git commit count of code revision to the version name. Its real handy in many situation. I ended up with below simple gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    def gitCommitCount = "git rev-list HEAD --count".execute().text.trim()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.8"
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".${gitCommitCount}"
        }

        release {
            versionNameSuffix ".${gitCommitCount}"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}
```

Similar to gitCommitCount, You can generate variables of your own to customise version name. As i am just executing a terminal command to store its result in a variable.

Comment: Nice idea. I'm now using git commit number for versionCode by getting the commit count across all branches and converting to an int: `def gitCommitCount = "git rev-list --all --count".execute().text.trim().toInteger()`

Answer (score 12):

This doesn't directly address your question of how to completely change the versionName, but this is what I use to append a suffix for my buildTypes:

```
defaultConfig {
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I know it, but `versionNameSuffix` initialises before any gradle task, so you can not change it from some task :(

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, to append DEBUG to my debug build to keep my logs clean. Tx!

Answer (score 5):

I just used [Javanator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34629268/5730063) and modified it a bit so that commit count not only helps in changing the name but also makes sure that version code also remains unique. Here is a sample of what I did (Maybe a couple of things can be optimized, but nevertheless does the job for me) :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    def gitCommitCount = "git rev-list HEAD --count".execute().text.trim().toBigInteger()
    project.ext.set("versionCode", gitCommitCount)
    project.ext.set("versionNameSuffix", "(${gitCommitCount})")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode  project.versionCode
        versionName "1.0"
        versionNameSuffix project.versionNameSuffix
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MyProject-$versionName")
        ....
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            .........
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        .....
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
}
```

***Edit :*** 
The last bit could also be like

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name.contains('release')) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "MyProject-${variant.versionName}${variant.versionCode}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar need of having separate build logic for release and non-release builds.
Apart from different versioning, I had to use a different set of dependencies, even different repositories.

None of the available plugins had all of the features that I needed, so I developed my own solution, based on simple approach - command line argument.

You can pass a command line parameter when invoking gradle build script like this:

```
gradle build -PmyParameter=myValue
```

or in my case

```
gradle build -PisRelease=true
```

Gradle will parse it, and it would automagically be available as a property of the project object.
You could then use it like this:

```
if (project.hasProperty('isRelease') && project.isRelease) {
        // Here be the logic!
}
```

I extracted this logic into a separate plugin, and I've been successfully using it across different projects.

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, I hope I gave you another angle to think about the problem and another possible solution.

Comment: This could be easily combined with the `incrementVersionNumber()` method in my answer! I use it too, you can even conditionally include modules in settings.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Both version name and version code can be generated dynamically as follows.
Comments in code.

```
/**
 * computedVersionCode()
 * do not name this to getVersionCode. getVersionCode conflicts with the automatic getter of versionCode
 * version code is an int a value between 0 and max int value 2147483647 is expected.
 * This function returns at int in yyyMMddHH format
 * For example, 2022061121 for 11 June 2022 between 21:00 to 21:59
 * This gives a new versioncode for every different hour of day and same code within same hour of hour of day
 * Max int value is 2147483647. So after year 2147 it will overflow to -ve values.
 * max value in year 2147 will be 2147121223 so Lot of scope of manually incrementing up-to 2147483647  will be there.
 * @return an int corresponding to current hour in yyyyMMddHH format
 */
static def computedVersionCode() {

    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHH')
    int versionCodeInt = (int) Long.parseLong(formattedDate)
    return versionCodeInt
}

/**
 * computedVersionCode2()
 * do not name this to getVersionCode. getVersionCode conflicts with automatic getter of versionCode
 * version code is an int a value between 0 and Max int value 2147483647 is expected.
 * This function returns total hours since epoch
 * For example, it returns 459711 for 11 June 2022 at 21:21 IST
 * This gives a new versioncode for every different hour
 * Max int value is 2147483647. This format is good till 09-Oct-246953 12:30:00 PM
 *
 * @return hours since epoch which can be used as version code
 */
static def computedVersionCode2() {

    long millisSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long hoursSinceEpoch = millisSinceEpoch/(3600*1000);
    int hoursSinceEpochInt = (int)hoursSinceEpoch;

    //Hours since epoch changes every hour automatically.
    //If data type int remains of same size forever this value will be good till year 4419.

    return hoursSinceEpochInt;
}

static def computedVersionSuffix() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd.HH.mm')
    return formattedDate
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
       ...
        versionCode computedVersionCode()
        versionName "1.0.8.".concat(computedVersionSuffix())
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question but you can try the below way to attach the dynamic build suffix to the `versionName` in `build.gradle` .

```
def buildCode = (int)(((new Date().getTime()/1000) - 1451606400) / 10)
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName "0.1.${buildCode}"
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done following:

```kotlin
val applicationName = "CoolApp"
android {
    applicationVariants.all {
        outputs.forEach {
            if (it is ApkVariantOutputImpl) {
                it.outputFileName = "$applicationName ${it.versionNameOverride}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle Wrapper: gradle-8.0
Android Gradle Plugin: 8.1.0

Hope this helps