# Android build with Gradle Release plugin

Tags: android, gradle, release, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use [Gradle Release Plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release) in `Android Project`.

I configured it and everything is okay, except one thing:

`Gradle Release Plugin` changes project version in `gradle.properties` file in one of its tasks, but this change does not affect `Android Project's` `versionName`, because as I found with using `println()` gradle initialising it before running any tasks.

Is there a way to change `Android Project` `versionName` in some gradle task after it was initialised?

Here is part of my `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 213
        versionName version // to change it, please visit gradle.properties file
        println('Project version: ' + version) // this line executed BEFORE any gradle task :(
    }

    ...
}
```

I can see only one solution: different gradle executions

1. Will change version in gradle.properties
2. Will execute build process, but this is bad workaround especially for `Gradle Release Plugin`

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.1.0 the [gradle-release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) is executing the build in a separate process. This ensures the version is correct throughout the build process and for all other plugins which rely on the version being set from the beginning.

> **2.1.0**
>
> ...
>
> COMMON: Refactored the build process during release to run in separate
>   process. This will hopefully resolve all the issues with certain other
>   plugins like the new maven-publish or the bintray plugin.
>
> COMMON: Added beforeReleaseBuild and afterReleaseBuild hook, which
>   both run in the same process as the build itself.
>
> ...

[see full changelog](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-2)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this functions in your build.gradle

```
task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++versionCode + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

task('incrementVersionName') << {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(4))
    def mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion + "." + (buildVersion + 1)
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName=\"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}


tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
        task.dependsOn 'incrementVersionName'
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I've created this gist.

The complete gist. https://gist.github.com/ascariandrea/9991499

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround I used which splits the execution of tasks into multiple gradle executions. It works for svn but can be adapted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26659974/256770