# How to split a gradle task execution

Tags: groovy, gradle

In my gradle project I have a task Task1 with many dependency tasks Task1Dep1, Task1Dep2, Task1Dep3... Task1DepN.
Is there a way to split my execution of Task1 such that Task1Dep1, Task1Dep2 in one execution and then run Task1Dep3 ... Task2DepN in a second execution.

The reason I want to do this is that if this is possible then it will be a solution to a problem I posted about here: [How to read latest property in property file that is updated earlier in gradle execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640983/how-to-read-latest-property-in-property-file-that-is-updated-earlier-in-gradle-e).

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "separate executions".

Comment: Hi Mark, see my answer below. Sorry I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue as follows.

The gradle task I wanted to run was the release task for running the [Townsfolk gradle-release plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release).

Normally this would be done as:

```
./gradlew release
```

Due to various issue sI ran into with the svn support in this plugin and using it with Android I had to split the underlying sub-tasks for this plugin as follows:

```
./gradlew -PusesSnapshot=true -PversionModified=true initScmPlugin checkCommitNeeded checkUpdateNeeded unSnapshotVersion  
./gradlew -PusesSnapshot=true -PversionModified=true initScmPlugin confirmReleaseVersion checkSnapshotDependencies build preTagCommit 
svn update
./gradlew -PusesSnapshot=true -PversionModified=true initScmPlugin createReleaseTag updateVersion commitNewVersion
```

I found the underlying tasks using:

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```