# How to debug android studio gradle files and tasks?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've leveraged TWiStErRob's solution [to auto-increment android versionNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414399/android-gradle-dynamically-change-versionname-at-build-time) and I have expanded on this to add more capability, however lately when I add the "apply from" statement in my build.gradle to include the auto-version.gradle file and let Gradle sync, my build.gradle gets inexplicably corrupted and loses all formatting using Android Studio 1.1.

Is there any way to debug or step through gradle scripts in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

The original answer you referenced did not modify the `build.gradle` so it should not be affected.  Please post your version of `auto-increment.gradle`.

Are you modifying the `build.gradle` programmatically?