# AndroidStudio/gradle can I assign variables based on previous variable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm just starting to play with gradle. Can I assign variables based on their previously assigned value? For instance, how can I use `versionName` from the defaultConfig in the free and paid flavors?

For instance, how could I use

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   ...
   productFlavors {
      free {
         versionName = versionName + "_free"
         ...
      }
      paid {
        ...
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

so versionName is `"1.0_free"` for the free flavor. Is this possible?

Comment: how about using `versionNameSuffix "_free"`?

Comment: You can use `versionNameSuffix`. As in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19184323/3942452)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how append date build to versionNameSuffix on gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172565/how-append-date-build-to-versionnamesuffix-on-gradle) and [How to set versionName in APK filename using gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332474/how-to-set-versionname-in-apk-filename-using-gradle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `versionNameSuffix "_free"`:

```
productFlavors {
      free {
         // you can also use this
         // applicationIdSuffix ".free"
         versionNameSuffix "_free"
         ...
      }
      paid {
        ...
      }
   }
```

For more information about the suffix, please visit [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) and [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)
.

Comment: Works -- but seems too specialized to me.  Works fine for VersionName but what if I want to do the same for ApplicationId.  Also, I've read several older comments on this that say things like "Yep, I know it, but versionNameSuffix initialises before any gradle task, so you can not change it from some task" eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414399/android-gradle-dynamically-change-versionname-at-build-time

Comment: Ah -- I see there is an applicationIdSuffix.  Where is this stuff documented?

Comment: @stevensmith: I've added the link for the documentation. Hope it help us ;)